# How does this code work in context with reduce function?

Tags: javascript

It might be a very basic question for people here but I have to ask away.
So I was going through reducce recently and I came through this example where I could find the maximum of some value in an array of object. Please, have a look at this code.

```
var pilots = [
    {
        id: 10,
        name: "Poe Dameron",
        years: 14
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Temmin 'Snap' Wexley",
        years: 30
    }, {
        id: 41,
        name: "Tallissan Lintra",
        years: 16
    }, {
        id: 99,
        name: "Ello Asty",
        years: 22
    }
];
```

If I write soemthing like this to find the maximum years,

```
var oldest_of_them_all = pilots.reduce(function (old, current) {
    var old = (old.years > current.years) ? old.years : current.years;
    return old
})
```

I get 22 as my value, and if I dont involve the property years, i.e-

```
var oldest_of_them_all = pilots.reduce(function (old, current) {
    var old = (old.years > current.years) ? old : current;
    return old
})
```

I get the object ***Object {id: 2, name: "Temmin 'Snap' Wexley", years: 30}*** as my value. Can someone explain why the first example is wrong and what is happening in there? Also, if I Just want to fetch the years value, how can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, as you are not returning the object there is no object property (*years*) of the accumulator (*old*) after the first iteration. Hence there is no *year* property to compare with.

```js
var pilots = [
    {
        id: 10,
        name: "Poe Dameron",
        years: 14
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Temmin 'Snap' Wexley",
        years: 30
    }, {
        id: 41,
        name: "Tallissan Lintra",
        years: 16
    }, {
        id: 99,
        name: "Ello Asty",
        years: 22
    }
];

var oldest_of_them_all = pilots.reduce(function (old, current) {
  console.log(old);// the value is not the object having the property years after the first iteration
  var old = (old.years > current.years) ? old.years : current.years;
  return old;
})
console.log(oldest_of_them_all);
```

Comment: @Yash, you are most welcome, I will suggest you to see the documentation before using such function:)